# What does \m mean in expression "l = \m -> ..."?

Tags: elm

```
    semOp l = \m -> case l of
                LD g -> case m of 
                    St xs -> St (g::xs)
                    _ -> Error
```

Just want to know what does the `\m` part is doing here.

Answer (score 9):

`\m -> ...` is syntax for [anonymous function](https://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#functions), aka "lambda-expression".

For example, the following two declarations would be equivalent:

```
f x = x + 5
f = \x -> x + 5
```

Both define a function with one parameter `x` that returns a number greater than `x` by 5.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add to Fyodor’s answer by saying that this is a slightly unusual way to write this - it’s making explicit that `semOp l` returns a lambda. The following are all valid and equivalent ways to write this function’s beginning:

```hs
semOp l m = case l of ..
semOp l   = \m -> case l of ..
semOp     = \l -> \m -> case l of ..
semOp     = \l m -> case l of ..
```

You might be most used to the first version, but in some languages like Haskell these can have slightly difference performance impacts - but this isn’t something for you to worry about, particularly in Elm as far as I understand.